# Why does Eclipse using port instead of javaw

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, serversocket, pid

After some time (Of idle or after some run launches) the proccess Eclipse.exe is using my specific wanted port.

It obvious that when Java program is running the proccess "javaw" is need to run and this process is using the port (In case of serversocket).
Why does **suddenly** Eclipse using my port?

[image: Eclipse process using my wanted port]

So when I running my application I get the predictable exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

**But when I restart Eclipse it release the port**

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason why Eclipse would use port 1617.  (It is reserved for "Nimrod Inter-agent Communication".)

I suspect that what has happened is that you have used Eclipse to run your application or some unit tests ... within the Eclipse JVM ... and there is a live ServerSocket still hanging around from the tests.

Try restarting Eclipse.

It is also possible that you are using a dodgy plugin which is ignoring the rules on port reservation ... just like your application is doing.

Comment: I forgot to say that when I restart Eclipse it release the port.
I don't want to restart Eclipse every time, there is another solution?

Comment: Yea.  Figure out if it is your unit tests, and if it is then fix them.

Comment: Did you attempt to launch your application from Eclipse?